# PHP 7 : Is there a possibility to change return data of function dynamically using reflection class or reflection method

Tags: php, oop, php-7

Let us consider this code

```
class MyClass {
  function __call($method, $arguments) {
     // I want to convert the return response from stdClass to SomeClass here and return
  }
}

Class UserClass extends Myclass
{
   protected function test(): SomeClass
   {
     $object = new stdClass();
     $object->id = 1;
     $object->name = 'some';
     return $object; 
   } 
}
```

I am creating object and trying to call protected function publicly

```
$userClass = new UserClass();
$userClass->test();
```

It will go to __call method as test method is not public

```
function __call($method, $arguments) {
  // I want to convert the return response from stdClass to SomeClass here and return
}
```

Here instead of returning value of type **SomeClass**, I am returning **object** of type **stdClass**. I want to convert this object to type of **SomeClass** before returning and throwing error.

```
protected function test(): SomeClass
{
   $object = new stdClass();
   $object->id = 1;
   $object->name = 'some';
   return $object; 
}
```

Is it possible using reflection method or something? Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: To me it would suggest that the design is wrong if you need to change the return type of a function.

Comment: Agreed. Use a different function to return a different type. Or don't declare a return type at all.

Comment: Hey @Mohd yer just gonna get ppl saying "don't do this" unless you better explain why you need to do it. Can you expand on why you need to do this? Also, can you ps clarify what you mean by "I want to convert this array to type of SomeClass before returning and throwing error". How are you planning on doing this "conversion"? It'll just be better if you gve us more details, I reckon ;-)

Comment: Reflection is for getting information about PHP functions, it doesn't change what they do.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. @AdamCameron I have edited the question, please check it and let me know if you have any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason why I am doing this because, there will be no class with name SomeClass, I will generate it dynamically, create instance of it, then want to assign to return data of function.

Comment: TBH why don't you just remove the return type declaration from the method? You don't *need* to specify one. And - merits or otherwise of your design aside - this is a case where it's appropriate to not have one.

Comment: @AdamCameron Thank you for the replay. I am working on some alternate way for this. My requirement is, I have a php file without PHP syntax and I have to generate its PHP equivalent class file and validate the data and its types while passed through it.. just like interface in typescript or struct in C.
Don't know whether I will be successful or not. But I made some progress recently, let's see how it goes...

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest what others have posted.
If you have two different cases, there should be two different functions handling the returned value. Each named after when one or the other type is returned ie:
`getUserArray` and `getUser` (if not within one class)

There is also another approach:
within `SomeClass` implement method `toArray` which returns object as an array instead of `self`. then you're also clear on where array come from and which structure it should follow. I advise keeping to the ValueObject instead of arrays where possible.